# getting the value of checked checkbox to remove from div with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

I have a doubt in selecting and verify that the `checkbox` is **checked** in a `div` with `id="div1"` which in turn is added in another `div` with `id = "box"` and the  result is **checkbox -> div.id = div1 -> divbox.id = box**

I have this base function to create `checkbox` and insert in `div1` and add `div1` to `div box` and it´s work and I don´t put the `css` code because don´t need

```
 function createCheckBox() {
   //count
   var count = 0;

   //create div1
   var div1 = document.createElement('div');
   div1.id = "div1";
   div1.style.fontSize = "20px";

   //div box 
   var divbox = document.createElement('div');
   divbox.id = "box";

   //checkbox
   var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
   checkbox.type = "checkbox";
   checkbox.name = "checkBox" + (count++);
   checkbox.id = checkbox.name;

   var label = document.createElement('label')
   label.htmlFor = "id";
   label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("checkBox" + (count++)));
   var br = document.createElement('br');

   div1.appendChild(checkbox);
   div1.appendChild(label);
   div1.appendChild(br);

   divbox.appendChild(div1);

   document.body.appendChild(divbox);
 }
```

my doubt is select checkbox check and return if is `checked` or not
and in this `function removeCheckBox` I wanna get value of checked checkbox
in this way **divbox.id = box -> div.id = div1 -> checkbox.checked** and it´s not work

```
function removeCheckBox() {
  //box
  var divbox = document.getElementById("box");
  //inside divbox select element with id = div1
  var div1 = divbox.getElementById("div1");

  for (var i = 0; div1.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (div1.childNodes[i].checked) {
      alert("CheckBox is checked");
      //remove from div1
      div1.removeChild(div1.childNodes[i]);
    } else {
      alert("CheckBox is not checked");
    }
  }
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `var div1 = divbox.getElementById("div1");` ... is it typo `divbox` or what? because I can't see anywhere definded `divbox`. That should be `var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");` or, maybe, just `var div1 = box.getElementById("div1");`, but that's no sense.

Comment: ok, I edit the `box` to `divbox` but `div1` is inside `divbox`

Comment: that's no matter. you define `div1` getting element by his `id`. and you nowhere define `divbox` in your `removeCheckBox` function. it's undefined.

Comment: also, typo: `childNodes.lenght`, `length` not `lenght`

Comment: thanks to identified the error, but still not work.  **inside divbox select element with id = div1**  `var div1 = divbox.getElementById("div1");`

Comment: I'm not quite sure: do You want to remove checkbox immediately when is checked or, for example, if you click some, let's called, remove button (and then will be removed all checked checkbox(es)?

Comment: yes @nelek,  I just  wanna to remove checkbox immediately when is checked nothing else and I add some code to doubt

Comment: then, in `function createCheckBox` add one more line, right after `checkbox.id=checkbox.name;` , `checkbox.setAttribute('onclick','removeCheckBox(this);');` and your complete function for removing will be `function removeCheckBox(ele) {document.getElementById('box').removeChild(ele.parentNode);}`. That will remove `div`, who is parent of checked checkbox. so, div and checkbox will be removed.... there is fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/5csc1a5p/

Comment: your logic is correct but the `function removeCheckBox` is called by  `btnRemove.onclick = function () {  removeCheckBox(); }`

Comment: this was my question in prev comment : **do You want to remove checkbox immediately when is checked or, for example, if you click some, let's called, remove button (and then will be removed all checked checkbox(es)?** and your answer was **yes @nelek, I just wanna to remove checkbox immediately when is checked** .... isn't? now, what you really want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112600/discussion-between-dsanches-and-nelek).

Comment: @nelek your logic is correct and you right but the event is with button not himself, that my mistake, i´m sorry

Comment: There is fiddle example, removing all checked checkbox(es) called by button click, https://jsfiddle.net/5csc1a5p/1/

Comment: @nelek, is that I talk about, thanks, this is the solution and it´s work with this last fiddle example [link] https://jsfiddle.net/5csc1a5p/1/ and may I put the solution or you did

Comment: finally :) ... i'll put it like answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is solution (description in code comment), based on all those comments :

```js
function removeCheckBox() {
  var box=document.getElementById('box');
  //get all checked checkboxes inside box div
  var chk=box.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  for(var i=0;i<chk.length;i++) {
   box.removeChild(chk[i].parentNode); //remove complete div, who is parent of checked checkbox
  }
}


function createCheckBox() {
  //count
  var count = 0;

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = "div1";
  div.style.fontSize = "20px";

  //div box 
  var box = document.getElementById('box');

  //checkbox
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "checkBox" + (count++).toString();
  checkbox.id = checkbox.name;
  
  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = "id";
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("checkBox" + (count++)));
  var br = document.createElement('br');

  div.appendChild(checkbox);
  div.appendChild(label);
  div.appendChild(br);

  box.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="create" onclick="createCheckBox();" />
<input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeCheckBox();" />
<br>
<div id="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many issues in the code. Your function should look something like this:

```
function selectCheckBox() {
    //box
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    //div1
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1"); //should be document not box

    for (var i = 0; i < div1.childNodes.length; i++) {//should be condition i < div1.childNodes.length, also not spelling of length
        if (div1.childNodes[i].type == 'checkbox') { //make sure it is a checkbox first
            if (div1.childNodes[i].checked) {
                alert("CheckBox is checked");
            } else {
                alert("CheckBox is not checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```